# Using queues to create loosely coupled and higher reliability applications - are local queues required for reliability?

Tags: azure, architecture, message-queue

I read [Queue-Centric Work Pattern (Building Real-World Cloud Apps with Azure)](https://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/queue-centric-work-pattern) which among other things speaks about using queues to increase reliability of applications.  First, a tightly coupled application is shown:

[image: Tight coupling]

They state:

> ...the web front-end is tightly coupled with the SQL Database
>   back-end. If the SQL database service is unavailable, the user gets an
>   error.

They then show a more loosely coupled approach:

[image: Loose coupling]

The benefit is stated as:

> If any of the backend services – such as the SQL database or the queue
>   listener -- go offline, users can still submit new Fix It tasks. The
>   messages will just queue up until the backend services are available
>   again.

**My question is - unless the queue exists *local* (and maybe just exist as a set of file system directories w/o a separate queue application running) to the application submitting the queue messages, don't we still have the same relability issue?**  Queues can break like database servers can break and the network connecting them can break the same.

(Granted, the article speaks of Microsoft's quoted reliabilities for their various services and shows queues as having slightly better uptime given their SLA's.  However, in this example I consider the fact that the application is on Azure and using Azure services to be an implementation detail.  I've certainly seen this pattern/architecture generalized.)  That's why I get back to my question about the locality of the queues.

Comment: This is really a discussion question, not a programming question, and it has no real answer. If you can't reach the queue service endpoint, then you'd have to come up with an alternative store for your messages (or drop messages). But just remember that the queue service has an SLA and runs independent of any single VM. Your app will have to provide adequate durability for your local storage, should the queue service be unreachable (and how you accomplish this is entirely up to you and your app).

Comment: Regarding "if you can't reach the queue service and point, then you will have to come up with an alternative store...", oh definitely.  That was actually the point I was trying to make -  that reaching the queue service and reaching the database endpoint are the same thing. Regarding the queue service having an sla and being independent of any single vm,  I see this as a particular service provider's implementation detail.  Is there something fundamentally different about a queue architecture  that gives greater reliability then a database for storing messages? (Part 1)

Comment: I feel as though there must be given the fact that this is a generalized pattern I see. Having moving parts is where stuff breaks and certainly queues have no fewer moving parts than a db.  Maybe it is because they are fundamentally designed to horizontally scale? (Part 2)